# Allocating memory for struct within a struct in cycle

Tags: c, parsing, memory-management, struct

I'm working on INI-style configuration parser for some project, and I gets next trouble.
I have 3 structures:

```
typedef struct {
    const char* name;
    unsigned tract;
    int channel;
    const char* imitation_type;
} module_config;

typedef struct {
    int channel_number;
    int isWorking;
    int frequency;
    int moduleCount;
} channel_config;

typedef struct {
    int mode;
    module_config* module;
    channel_config* channel;
} settings;
```

And I have function for handling data in my INI-file (I working under [inih](http://pastebin.com/eRj824Sz) parser): [pasted to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/eRj824Sz) cause too long]. Finally, in main(), I did the next:

```
settings* main_settings;
main_settings = (settings*)malloc(sizeof(settings));
main_settings->module = (module_config*)malloc(sizeof(module_config));
main_settings->channel = (channel_config*)malloc(sizeof(channel_config));
if (ini_parse("test.ini", handler, &main_settings) < 0) {
    printf("Can't load 'test.ini'\n");
    return 1;
}
```

In result, binary crashes with memory fault. I think (no, I KNOW), what I'm incorrectly allocating the memory in handler(), but I does not understand, where I do it wrong. I spent all night long trying to understand memory allocating, and I'm very tired, but now me simply interestingly, what I'm doing wrong, and HOW to force this working fine.
P.S. Sorry for ugly english

Comment: Why not just store the two structs inside the third, without pointers?  The pointer indirection seems unnecessary.

Comment: flagged as "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: @JohnZwinck cause modules and channels amount can be any. Therefore I also dynamically allocate memory to module and channel in main

Comment: Do you receive any syntax warning during compile? It appears you want: `main_settings = malloc (sizeof (struct settings));` Unless you have a `typedef` defined for `struct settings`. The included structs would be e.g. : `main_settings->module = malloc (sizeof (struct module_config));`. In all cases **do not** cast the return of `malloc`. It is just another opportunity for error.

Comment: Where's the "cycle" you've mentioned in your title? If you speak Russian, you most probably meant a [*loop*](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson3.html), but I don't see any of these in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the reallocation of your structs:

```
pconfig = (settings *) realloc(pconfig, (module_count + channel_count) * sizeof(channel_config));
pconfig->module = (module_config *) realloc(pconfig->module, module_count * sizeof(module_config));
pconfig->channel = (channel_config *) realloc(pconfig->channel, channel_count * sizeof(channel_config));
```

First of all, you must not reallocate the main settings struct. Since your handler will always be called with the original `pconfig` value, the reallocation of the `module` and `channel` arrays has no effect, and you'll access freed memory.

Also when reallocating the `module` and `channel` arrays you should allocate `count + 1` elements, since the next invocation of `handler` might assign to the `[count]` slot.

So try to replace the three lines above with:

```
pconfig->module  = (module_config *)  realloc(pconfig->module,  (module_count + 1)  * sizeof(module_config));
pconfig->channel = (channel_config *) realloc(pconfig->channel, (channel_count + 1) * sizeof(channel_config));
```

Comment: Also note that assigning the result of `realloc()` to its first argument is always a bad idea, because it leads to a memory leak when `realloc()` fails.